# Triying to run VLC for unity plugin demo

Tags: unity-game-engine, vlc, libvlcsharp

This is the repo: https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc-unity

I was finally able to build the plugin, but when I try to run the example in unity, a couple of exceptions appear:

Assets\VLC-Unity-Windows\Scripts\UseRenderingPlugin.cs(32,25): error CS1061: 'MediaPlayer' does not contain a definition for 'SetTime' and no accessible extension method 'SetTime' accepting a first argument of type 'MediaPlayer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Assets\VLC-Unity-Windows\Scripts\UseRenderingPlugin.cs(95,40): error CS1061: 'MediaPlayer' does not contain a definition for 'GetTexture' and no accessible extension method 'GetTexture' accepting a first argument of type 'MediaPlayer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Plugins: Failed to load 'Assets / VLC-Unity-Windows / Plugins / x86_64 / plugins / VLCUnityPlugin.dll' because one or more of its dependencies could not be loaded.

I am using these versions of dlls, located on unity plugin folder: LibVLCSharp v3.4.3.0 libvlc.dll v3.0.8.0 libvlccore.dll v3.0.8.0

and the last version of the repository.

could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

To make this work, you need:

- LibVLCSharp Unity build netstandard2.0 (version 4.0),
- Nightly libvlc 4 llvm x64 build
- Build of the Unity C++ plugin

It's still a bit rough around the edges, lacks some samples but it will get better with time :-)

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Could you please explain me how or where to get this: LibVLCSharp Unity build netstandard2.0 (version 4.0).

Comment: I just clone the repository and build the unity branch, and get the dll from netstandard2.0. 
Also, i get the last version of vlc nightly builds. now the libraries have version 4.0.0.
Still getting the same exceptions.

Comment: Look at the Unity branch how to make a Unity build. You're missing a define.