# Executing VLC for unity

Tags: libvlcsharp, vlc-unity

I am facing similar issue like this mentioned in the post:

[Triying to run VLC for unity plugin demo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60992563/triying-to-run-vlc-for-unity-plugin-demo)

Build platform is **WIN 10 x64 (build 2004)**.

I am using **LibVLC** from the nightly build: https://artifacts.videolan.org/vlc/nightly-win64-llvm/20200914-0434/

**LibVLCSharp** gets built successfully (https://code.videolan.org/videolan/LibVLCSharp/-/tree/master/).

I was trying to build "**VLCUnityPlugin.dll**" but failing (have installed https://github.com/mstorsjo/llvm-mingw/tree/20200325 (LLVM MinGW)), using MSYS64 to run ./build.sh and it was coming up with this error:

[MSYS error while building VLCUnity plugin dll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ya11l.png)

I thought maybe since "VLCUnityPlugin.dll" is NOT present, Unity x64 (v 2019.4.8f1) keeps on complaining with the following errors:

[UNITY errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nZbtB.png)

But after, I hacked "common" make file as shown below:

[make file changes to build VLCUnityPlugin.dll](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nud46.png)
I successfully built VLCUnityPlugin.dll and my plugin file structure looks like this now:
[Plugin directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LEd0N.png)

Still, I do see **UNITY Errors**:
"Assets\VLCUnity\Demos\Scripts\MinimalPlayback.cs(99,39): error CS1061: 'MediaPlayer' does not contain a definition for 'GetTexture' and no accessible extension method 'GetTexture' accepting a first argument of type 'MediaPlayer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/4064749/mfkl thoughts ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The free trial version is available for download here https://videolabs.io/vlc-unity/vlc-unity-windows-trial.unitypackage.

That being said, if you want to build it yourself, you should follow what the CI does https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc-unity/-/blob/master/.gitlab-ci.yml

The libvlcsharp build is a special one, you need to define UNITY when you build it. It has the added GetTexture method.

For VLCPlugin.dll, you should crosscompile from Linux, where you install llvm-mingw and run it from bash (for example). MSYS not needed.

Comment: Thank you @mfkl, it worked with your suggestions and my hacks. Now, I am headed towards making it work for UNITY UWP Platform.

Comment: Also, I found that Lib VLC nightly builds are missing folder for SDK in zip files. It has them in 7z files.

Comment: Also, trial version is missing VLCUnityPlugin.dll